# Sync Framework. Composite PK, setting on syncronization

Tags: database-design, microsoft-sync-framework

Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient](
    [GuidClient] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IdClient] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [IdClient] ASC,
    [GuidClient] ASC
)
```

Clients:

```
CREATE TABLE [Patient] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    [GuidClient] [uniqueidentifier] -- this always null, for Sync Framework
)
```

On downloading from client to server I set actual value to GuidClient column:

```
remote.ChangesSelected += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Context.DataSet.Tables.Contains(patTbl))
    {
        var dataTable = e.Context.DataSet.Tables[patTbl];
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[j];
            row["GuidClient"] = clientGuid;
        }
    }
}
```

Question 1: How to handle deletions if we need to delete on server? Because GuidClient on server is PK, we need to set value to GuidClient column, as I understand 515 error (Cannot Insert The Value NULL Into Column...). Something like

```
row.RejectChanges();
row["GuidClient"] = clientGuid;
row.Delete();
```

Question 2: This schema with "virtual" PK will not work to download changes from server to client, right?

Comment: not sure i understand your Question 1  - if you want to upload Deletes, then it should be the same process. nothing special. Question 2 - it should work, you know what the client's guid is. also, you've already modified your client's table to add a guid, why not have the guid set on the table itself rather than intercepting and adding the guid at runtime?

Comment: 1. Maybe because of that guid-adding, on client actual value of GuidClient is NULL, and on server it is NOT NULL. 2. And every row on every table will have the same guidclient value? Looks strange.

Comment: 1 - you intercept and inject guid so why would it be null? 2 - your PK is a compound key, what the use of having unique guids when both id and guid makes it unique on the server already? besides, having the client guid for each client means you can trace back from which client a row came from

Comment: "why not have the guid set on the table itself" you mean unique guid per row here? I want one guid pre client. Thats why I add that fake column. And problem is: when Delete,  I cant intercept and add right guid value.

Comment: per client is what am suggesting.

Comment: Ok. And how to insert that guid value for each row on server side?